# CosmosDB insertion loop stops inserting after a certain number of iterations (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, azure-cosmosdb

I'm doing a few tutorials on CosmosDB. I've got the database set up with the Core (SQL) API, and using Node.js to interface with it. for development, I'm using the emulator.

This is the bit of code that I'm running:

```
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

const options = {
      endpoint: 'https://localhost:8081',
      key: REDACTED,
      userAgentSuffix: 'CosmosDBJavascriptQuickstart'
    };

const client = new CosmosClient(options);

(async () => {
    let cost = 0;
    let i = 0

    while (i < 2000) {
        i += 1
        console.log(i+" Creating record, running cost:"+cost)
        let response = await client.database('TestDB').container('TestContainer').items.upsert({}).catch(console.log);
        cost += response.requestCharge;       
    }
})()
```

This, without fail, stops at around iteration 1565, and doesn't continue. I've tried it with different payloads, without much difference (it may do a few more or a few less iterations, but seems to almsot always be around that number)

On the flipside, a similar .NET Core example works great to insert 10,000 documents:

```
double cost = 0.0;
            int i = 0;

            while (i < 10000)
            {
                i++;
                ItemResponse<dynamic> resp = await this.container.CreateItemAsync<dynamic>(new { id = Guid.NewGuid() });
                cost += resp.RequestCharge;
                Console.WriteLine("Created item {0} Operation consumed {1} RUs. Running cost: {2}", i, resp.RequestCharge, cost);
            }
```

So I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Why are you doing upserts in your node.js example? Can you try with Create? Also, is there no exception returned?

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit of fiddling, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with CosmosDB or it's library.

I was running this in the debugger, and Node would just crap out after x iterations. I noticed if I didn't use a `console.log` it would actually work. Also, if I ran the script with `node file.js` it also worked. So there seems to be some sort of issue with debugging the script while also printing to the console. Not exactly sure whats up with that, but going to go ahead and mark this as solved